# Cmake doesn't see variable from find_path

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to compile code with activemq-cpp with cmake and gcc 5.4

```
find_path(ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR NAMES cms/Config.h HINTS $ENV{ACTIVEMQDIR})
```

Here ACTIVEMQDIR is an environment variable set to

> /usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.10.0

```
message(STATUS ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR=${ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR})

include_directories(${ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR})
```

//include_directories(/usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.10.0)
If i hardcode path explicitly, then it is ok...

Output from cmake:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- 1=/usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.10.0
-- 2=/usr/local/lib
-- 3=/usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.10.0
-- 4=/usr/local/lib/libactivemq-cpp.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to
    -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
    -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
```

## ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR=/usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.10.0

```
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/oem/ClionProjects/untitled/b2
```

The problem is that `include_directories(${ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR})` doesn't work. Variable `ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR` is not set

Comment: What is commented `ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR=` line, which is shown with *LARGE bold* font? What is a meaning of the second part of CMake output (indented)? It is very similar to the first part (unindented). Please, fix content and formatting of your question post. Currently It is difficult to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Write it like this
`include_directories($ENV{ACTIVEMQCPP_DIR})`
so that [cmake knows it's an environemnt variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/ENV.html).